# Why does a response vector of type geometry_msgs/PoseStamped[] poses in a service always has 24 elements? (c++)

Tags: ros, c++, services

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I can't explain what is happening, maybe it is just my compiler, or my ROS version, but every time that I want to use the response vector poses (of type geometry_msgs/PoseStamped[]) it has 24 places, so if I ask for the size before assigning any value to it:

```
bool generate_robot_targets_service(robot_pick_place::GenerateRobotTargets::Request  &req, robot_pick_place::GenerateRobotTargets::Response &res){    
        int poses_size = sizeof(res.poses);
        std::cout << "The size of poses is:  " << poses_size << std::endl;//shows: The size of poses is: 24
        return true;
}
```

poses_size is equal to 24. **Why?**
I try to delete the 24 ? (whatever they are) using the erase() vector method and it gives a core dumped error (like always).
I could try creating a vector pointer and assigning it to the res.poses to point to the new memory, but still, **Why does it start with 24 positions filled with garbage?**

Any idea is welcome, please comment.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237517/why-does-a-response-vector-of-type-geometry_msgs/posestamped%5B%5D-poses-in-a-service-always-has-24-elements?-(c++)/) by [pablocesar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20992/pablocesar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 252 on 2016-06-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`sizeof()` returns the [size in bytes of the object representation of the respective type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof). Thus, on a 64bit system (I'm assuming you have this), this is 24 bit for a vector (see e.g. [this blog post, first bullet point](http://info.prelert.com/blog/stl-container-memory-usage)), if it is empty.

If you want to have the number of elements, use `res.poses.size()` ([see here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/size/)).

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pablocesar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20992/pablocesar/) on 2016-06-20**:
Sorry, it is actually my mistake (a basic one, I guess I'm sleepy) for being using a vector as an array, for vectors it is indeed vector.size() for getting the size of it, thanks!